# MongoDB convert set of arrays to tree structure

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents stored in a MongoDB collection - the documents map to a position in a hierarchy using an array:

db.docs.find({})

```
{
    _id : 564a22329a8cbd78022738f6,
    path: ['root','people','janice','orders'],
    name: "janice-order-1",
    value: 36
},
{
    _id : 564a22329a8cbd78022738f7,
    path: ['root','people','george','sales'],
    nameL "george-sale-1",
    value:19
}
```

This is equivalent to a tree structure:

```
root
  people
    janice
      orders
        janice-order-1 : 36
    george
      sales
        george-sale-1  : 19
```

I would like to be able to query, for a given `treeposition` (e.g. `['root','people']`) and a given `depth`, e.g. `2`, what branches of the tree exist:

```
> branches(['root','people'], 2)
{
    "janice":{
       "orders":null
    },
    "george":{
       "sales":null
    }
}

> branches([], 4)
 {"root":{
    "people":{
      "janice":{
        "orders":null
       }
      "george":{
        "sales": null
      }
    }
  }
```

Can I do this in an elegant way with MongoDB?

Comment: People keep upvoting questions like this as a "wanted feature" ( that much is clear, though not really in  the "upvoting guidelines" ), but the basics are the aggregation framework does not "create keys" in output objects. If you want this, then use `mapReduce` instead, which with JavaScript manipulation can create keys from variable content. I profess that I don't think it's a good idea and contrary to clean object design. *"Properties are properties"* and *"Data is data"* and should stay that way. Most times, this is done on the perception that some library needs input this way. Likely not.